# Cannot make Type work while working with protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui

I just made a function for modifying views, the code builds itself, but when I am using it it complaints about Type issue related to protocol, it must be an easy fix, but I could not solve it.

```
struct CGSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: CGSize { get { return CGSize() } }
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) { value = nextValue() }
    
}

extension View {
    
    func onPreference<K: PreferenceKey>(key: K, value: K.Value, action: ((K.Value) -> Void)?) -> some View where K.Value: Equatable {
        return self
            .preference(key: K.self, value: value)
            .onPreferenceChange(K.self, perform: { newValue in action?(newValue)})
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
struct ContentTestView: View {
    
    @State private var size: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button("update") { size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) }
         .onPreference(key: CGSizePreferenceKey, value: size, action: { newValue in print(newValue) })
    }
}
```

Errors:

> Instance method 'onPreference(key:value:action:)' requires that 'CGSizePreferenceKey.Type.Value' conform to 'Equatable'
>
> Cannot convert value of type 'CGSize' to expected argument type 'CGSizePreferenceKey.Type.Value'

Comment: Updated in question, thanks. @Cristik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you should change the definition of `onPreference` to accept a meta-type instead of an instance of `K`, the simple reason being that you never use that instance of `K`, SwiftUI doesn't ask for an instance of `PreferenceKey` in that context.

```swift
extension View {    
    func onPreference<K: PreferenceKey>(key: K.Type, value: K.Value, action: @escaping (K.Value) -> Void) -> some View where K.Value: Equatable {
```

I also took the liberty of removing the optionality of the `action` parameter, since it makes little sense to call `onPreference` without a callback.

Now, with the new definition in place, what's left is to update the call site to pass the meta-type:

```swift
.onPreference(key: CGSizePreferenceKey.self, ...
```

Note that a shorter solution would've been to just instantiate the preference at the call site:

```swift
.onPreference(key: CGSizePreferenceKey(), ...
```

, that would've make the compiler happy, however it wouldn't have been the right solution.

Comment: Your code is working, but I did not understand how your answer solved the issue? For you may is a simple issue, but for me it is not, As you can see the SwiftUI modifier of **preference** needs a type that conform to PreferenceKey, and I just satisfied it, the things are not clear for me why I need use Type in code. It is not about copy and paste the answer, I want understand it.

Comment: @Mada as I explained in the answer,`onPreference` was requiring an instance of that type `K` as the first parameter, which didn't make much sense as SwiftUI doesn't ask for instances, it only asks for the type itself.

Comment: Thanks, now I have a problem to understand when some parameter asking for an instance of a protocol or the protocol itself, is there a way to know about it?

Comment: Well, that's easy, @Mada, if function signature asks for `K` it needs an instance, if it asks for `K.Type` is needs a meta-type. `.Type` denotes the need for a meta-type instead of an instance.